# Determining camera orientation from an image/render

Tags: camera, image, axis, transform-orientation

I try to recreate certain scenes in blender from renders and images, and I'm having a hard time setting the camera correctly and accurately.

As of now, to set up the camera position of a scene I want to recreate, I place the image/render in the background and manually move the camera until certain elements in the scene are perfectly aligned with the image in the background. (I know the exact location of given elements in the scene) This procedure takes too long and almost impossible sometimes.

Note: I know the correct camera focal length and sensor size, it's only the rotation, location and zoom I need to know.

I'll provide a simple example, for clarification:

I have the following scene:

[image: Example 1]

and I want to reposition the the camera in given scene to match the position and angle as in this image:

[image]

I know the the exact location of the base object (and thus, the exact coordinates of each vertex), I also have the XY grid to use as another reference in this case.

I there a way, using a python script/add-on/external software/ect, to do this?

I think theoretically it should be possible using maths, or by iteratively moving the camera to align with the image using a python script, but I don't know how to properly implement it.

I have tried using fSpy and a similar blender add-on, and they get the camera position wrong every time, and when I import the fSpy file into blender, the camera settings are wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think fspy is probably the best for it. It's quite finicky, and can take some time and fiddling (and much frustration) to get it right, but I still think it's the best. Make sure you set the axes in fspy to Z-up, -Y forward (I'm pretty sure blender is -Y forward, maybe double check that part).

Comment: You would need to know the 35mm equivalent of the focal length of the lens, but if you had it you would the basically duplicate the math fspy uses, once you've give it axis to work with.  A fspy tip that you probably already know:  Hold the shift key down when moving the axis lines to get a magnified view of the image.